# Why does the poem "I Love" seem to imply that Belarus is fertile?

Tags: poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire, kanstancyja-bujla

Follow-up to: [Is Belarus actually hard to farm?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19688/is-belarus-actually-hard-to-farm)

The poem *I love* by Kanstancyja Bujla contains the following lines:

> I love our Byelorussian nation,
> Cottages where green orchards throng,
> The ploughlands, gleaming gold with harvest,
> Our woods and groves, their murmured song...
>
> I love the spring, adorning gladly
> The earth with flowers and green anew,
> The storks a-chatter at their nesting,
> The song of skylarks love I too.

This seems to run directly contrary to many of the other poems in the same collection that complain about how difficult Belarus is to farm. Can someone explain this apparent contradiction? Why does this author's experience seem to be so contrary to the experience of other authors in the collection?

Comment: Are ‘hard to farm’ and ‘fertile’ contradictory?

Comment: Belarus is a decent-sized country, with several different types of habitat contained within it, as mentioned in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's true; that being said, does this just come down to the authors coming from different parts of the country (or of this poem being written later after the land had been improved a little more)?

Comment: Does your collection include the original dates of publication of these poems? It would be interesting to see if there's a significant time difference between this one and others that complain about its difficulty to farm.

Comment: First of all, the poem is about **Homeland**. Doesn't it touch your heart at all? Don't look for agricultural prosperity issues in it. Actually, it wonders me I should write this.