# Why did the war-trenches get leveled over with sand?

Tags: poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire, maksim-tank

The Belarusian poem *It would be well* by Maksim Tank (which was written in the aftermath of brutal fighting in Belarus during WWII) included the following line:

> The winds level over our war-torn trenches with sand

Why was this? Is this related to the [poor soil quality in parts of Belarus](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19688/is-belarus-actually-hard-to-farm)? Is the soil really *that* sandy, or is this hyperbole?